LTSM doesn't fit correctly
The accuracy after the training of my model is very poor.
Why?
Link for the example dataset: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kSZNlR0AKgLNSITq_pVxXA6eBJ5nzB5Q/view?usp=sharing
There are the inputs:

Input 1) 6-50 (in the current dataset for sake of semplicity we have only 6 (normalized)
Input 2) 0-3168 (normalized)
Input 3) The sequence (1-13 + 0 for the mask)

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Embedding, LSTM, Dense, Concatenate, Masking
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def train(max_path_len, num_outputs, csv_file):
    sequence_length = max_path_len
    num_classes = num_outputs
    embedding_dim = 8
    sequenza_len = num_outputs + 1  # +1 because of 0 padding

    stack_input = Input(shape=(1,), name='stack')
    stack_dense = Dense(8, activation='relu')(stack_input)

    cluster_input = Input(shape=(1,), name='cluster')
    cluster_dense = Dense(8, activation='relu')(cluster_input)
    sequenza_input = Input(shape=(sequence_length,), name='sequenza')
    masked_sequenza = Masking(mask_value=0)(sequenza_input)
    embedded_sequenza = Embedding(input_dim=sequenza_len, output_dim=embedding_dim, input_length=sequence_length, mask_zero=True)(masked_sequenza)
    lstm_out = LSTM(64, return_sequences=False)(embedded_sequenza)
    lstm_dense = Dense(32, activation='relu')(lstm_out)
    lstm_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(lstm_dense)

    merged = Concatenate()([stack_dense, cluster_dense, lstm_dense])
    output = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='output')(merged)
    model = Model(inputs=[stack_input, cluster_input, sequenza_input], outputs=output)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    sequenza_data = data['sequenza'].apply(lambda x: [int(i) for i in x.split('-')]).tolist()
    stack_data = data['stack'].to_numpy()
    cluster_data = data['cluster'].to_numpy()
    sequenza_data = np.array(sequenza_data)
    outputN = [f"output{o}" for o in range(1, num_outputs+1)]
    output_data = data[outputN].to_numpy()
    output_data = output_data / output_data.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)

    model.fit(
        [stack_data, cluster_data, sequenza_data],
        output_data,
        batch_size=128,
        epochs=50,
        validation_split=0.2
    )

train(max_path_len=9, num_outputs=13, "./dataset.csv")

